# Referencing equation like a figure

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, numbering

I have made an arrow equation (xymatrix) with text. Now I need to reference it like a figure. Any ideas how to achieve that.

If I put in `\label{}` it will be numbered according equations. I need it to be numbered according figures.

```
\begin{equation*}
\xymatrix{
\text{some text} \ar@<-2pt>[d]_{A}  \\
\text{more technigal jargon} \ar@<-2pt>[d]_{B} \\
\text{even more} \ar@<-2pt>[u]
} 
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: `equation*` does not use a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`equation*` does not use equation (or whatever numbers). Either use `equation` and something like `\label[figure]{foo}` with `cleveref` package or use a `\tag` approach.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{cleveref}



\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]
\begin{equation}
\xymatrix{%
\text{some text} \ar@<-2pt>[d]_{A}  \\
\text{more technigal jargon} \ar@<-2pt>[d]_{B} \\
\text{even more} \ar@<-2pt>[u]
} \label[figure]{foo}
\end{equation}

In \cref{foo} we see
\end{document}
```